# Flickering Error when I import my .fbx into Unreal Engine (after sculpting)

Tags: .fbx, unreal-engine

When I export my Blender-Project and load it into Unreal Engine, it looks like this. Why?

[image]

Comment: importing the fbx back into blender might solve the mystery

Comment: You export as .fbx? Have you tried adjusting the parameters?